# Is it possible to have python package rpy2==3.5.13 deployed on a .NET framework

Tags: python, r, .net, rpy2

I'm not too familiar with how application deployments work and was wondering if the package rpy2[link](https://rpy2.github.io/) running through a python backend would work because it has dependencies on R executable. If this is possible how would it go about being set up?